# Asp.Net MVC Input Validation still firing after being disabled

Tags: asp.net-mvc, xss

I've disabled `validateRequest` in my web.Config, but the app is still firing the error:

> A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client

I've got the following in my web.Config

```
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
    <pages validateRequest="false">
```

I've also tried the following in my controller to no avail

```
<ValidateInput(False)> _
<AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)> _
Function Edit(ByVal user As Domain.User, ByVal id As Integer) As ActionResult
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer found
[Why is ValidateInput(False) not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807662/why-is-validateinputfalse-not-working)

You have to set the ValidInput in the Controller AND in the web.Config.

```
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
```