# ASP.NET MVC 3 ValidateRequest(false) not working with FormCollection

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

FYI I am using .NET 4.0 / MVC 3.

In my controller, the following is my code:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ViewResult Edit(ContentTemplateView contentTemplateView, FormCollection collection)
```

Everything works fine when I don't enter HTML, so I know the proper controller is being fired.  Also, I have following set properly in my web.config files:

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0"/>
```

I only get this problem when I include the FormCollection (which is needed for this particular Controller).  So what exactly am I doing wrong?

[I have done what was proposed on the following questions, and they work as long as there is no FormCollection.  None of them offer a solution with an included FormCollection]

- [Why is ValidateInput(False) not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807662/why-is-validateinputfalse-not-working)
- [Asp.Net MVC Input Validation still firing after being disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3135582/asp-net-mvc-input-validation-still-firing-after-being-disabled)
- [ValidateInput Attribute Doesn't Seem To Work in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461330/validateinput-attribute-doesnt-seem-to-work-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think I've solved my own riddle, with the help of this forum: http://forums.asp.net/p/1621677/4163625.aspx

I just modified my Controller so that it didn't accept the Controller, and instead grabbed the unvalidated form collection from the Request [with the help of System.Web.Helpers].

```
using System.Web.Helpers;

[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ViewResult Edit(ContentTemplateView contentTemplateView)
{
    FormCollection collection = new FormCollection(Request.Unvalidated.Form);
```

Comment: BTW I believe this bug is fixed for the next release of ASP.NET MVC 3, so this workaround won't be needed when you upgrade to that release.

Comment: I have tried to add a reference to the `System.Web.Helpers` dll, and added a `using System.Web.Helpers` in my controller, but it wont accept `Unvalidated()` as a method under `Request`. Im using .NET 4 and MVC 3 RC.

Comment: @Martin just answered your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392186/validate-request-with-request-unvalidated-in-asp-mvc-3-rc-and-net-4

Comment: This help help to resolve my problem! I have this problem "Preventing CSRF With Ajax" (http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/10/preventing-csrf-with-ajax.aspx) but this is fired before ValidateInput(false) so I replace  _form = new NameValueCollection(request.Form); with  _form = new NameValueCollection(request.Unvalidated().Form);

Comment: Yes, it works. You should also add the following to web.config <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />

Answer (score 7):

I just installed ASP.NET MVC 3 RC2, and this bug has been fixed.  The following code works as expected now.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ViewResult Edit(FormCollection form)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using custom model binders and *[ValidateInput(false)]* is not working then you might find a solution here: http://blogs.taiga.nl/martijn/2011/09/29/custom-model-binders-and-request-validation/