# Validate request with Request.Unvalidated() in ASP MVC 3 RC and .NET 4

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-4.0

I have the same problem as below:

[ASP.NET MVC 3 ValidateRequest(false) not working with FormCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361907/asp-net-mvc-3-validaterequestfalse-not-working-with-formcollection)

I have tried to add a reference to the `System.Web.Helpers` dll, and added a using `System.Web.Helpers` in my controller, but it wont accept `Unvalidated()` as a method under `Request`. Im using .NET 4 and MVC 3 RC.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Unvalidated()` extension method is defined in the `System.Web.WebPages.dll` assembly, not `System.Web.Helpers.dll` (but still in the `System.Web.Helpers` namespace)

Sorry for the confusion.