# How can I access unvalidated items in the Request.Form collection in MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, httpwebrequest

I am using ASP.NET MVC 3 with .NET 4.0.  I have a model on which one of the properties requires that HTML content be allowed.  I have placed the `AllowHtml` attribute on my model property which allows HTML on that property.  That works by itself.

I am also using the [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) flash uploader on other parts of my website.  Due to [problems](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/using-sessions-with-uploadify/) with flash and sessions, I'm using some code similar to the code in a [swfupload example](http://code.google.com/p/swfupload/source/browse/swfupload/trunk/samples/samples/asp.net/Global.cs.asax) to allow my file upload access to session data.  Basically I'm accessing the `Request.Form` collection directly in the `Application_BeginRequest` handler.

The problem I'm running into is that when the form that allows HTML is posed I get a `HttpRequestValidationException` when the code in the `Application_BeginRequest` handler access the `Request.Forms[key]` collection.

Like I said in the beginning, I've tried the `AllowHtml` attribute.  I've also tried disabling validation at the action and controller level using the `ValidateInput(false)` attribute, but I believe I'm too early in the request life cycle for those to apply.  Is there anyway to access the `Request.Form` collection containing "potentially dangerous" data without disabling request validation for the entire site?

Comment: Could you disalbe validation in web.config <system.web><httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" /></system.web>

Comment: Yes, but that will disable validation for the entire site.  I would prefer to keep it enabled if possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You asking about something like this: [Validate request with Request.Unvalidated() in ASP MVC 3 RC and .NET 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392186/validate-request-with-request-unvalidated-in-asp-mvc-3-rc-and-net-4) ?

```
Request.Unvalidated().Params[""]
```

Comment: Yes, `Unvalidated()` fixes the issue.  Thank you very much.

Comment: I needed to use `Request.Unvalidated().Form[""]` maybe because I am using ASP.Net Web Pages 2.0 (C# with Razor / WebMatrix)

Answer (score 0):

For the record, another way of doing this is by creating an unvalidated object:

```
var unvalidatedRequest = System.Web.Helpers.Validation.Unvalidated(Request);
```

Then you only have to access the `unvalidatedRequest` object rather than repeatedly hitting `Unvalidated()`.

The [`Validation.Unvalidated`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.validation_methods(v=vs.111).aspx) method has various overloads.