# MVC potentially dangerous Request.QueryString value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, urlencode

I have search field on Page.
When I try to search by `<` all works fine. But if try search by `<!` it fails.
I have simple controller method:

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Index(string filter)
{
    var items = data.GetItems(filter);
    var listViewModel = ListViewModel(items)
    return View(listViewModel);
}
```

Exception occurs on **last** line of code, when view returns.

UPD:

My view is quite big. On this view I use WebGrid.
So in debug app fails on this line:

```
var gridHtml = grid.GetHtml(
            tableStyle: "grid",
            headerStyle: "header",
            footerStyle: "footer",
            alternatingRowStyle: "alternative",
            columns: Model.Columns,
            numericLinksCount: Model.NumericLinksCount,
            mode: WebGridPagerModes.All

            );
```

Comment: You should probably add your view code and markup

Comment: have you tried the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/807662/why-is-validateinputfalse-not-working/2530823#2530823

Comment: @danefairbanks yes, sure but that didn't help me

Answer (score 0):

Encoding on client side and decoding on server side solve my problem, but I'm still not sure if this better way.